# how sharing & annotation/marking on shared holograms works on new Mixed Reality ToolKit (MRTK) for unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, toolkit, mrtk, mr-spectatorview

I'm looking for solution to get rid of old version of `MRTK` and start using new version of MRTK for Unity sharing applications.

but i am no sure still the new version is supporting sharing as well as annotation or marking on shared holographic objects.

i had tried to find out the solution everywhere on Google and youtube to draw circle or highlight the part of shared object. 
still i did not able to get the solution.

Comment: i am aware about the sharing how it works and we also require and sharing service.exe should be running among the network. but i am not sure about new `MRTK` and **marking the objects**

Comment: What do you mean by "draw circle" or "highlight part of the shared object"? It sounds like you have an existing version of the MRTK that works, but that you then wish to upgrade to a newer version. Is this correctly understood? If yes, please show screenshots of the existing and what it does.

Comment: @Doh09 yes, I have one version of Unity3D application, which is working fine with sharing the objects between hololense, now among this sharing, I would like to give feature to user like on shared object then can mark something like mentioning in another comment

Comment: @Doh09 [Ref Image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiUuOSdhL7iAhWjguYKHcSyCToQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=%2Furl%3Fsa%3Di%26source%3Dimages%26cd%3D%26ved%3D%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.vectorstock.com%252Froyalty-free-vector%252Fsave-the-date-with-red-circle-mark-on-calendar-vector-21009559%26psig%3DAOvVaw3NsIeeVQfpCNDWg-FuLAVU%26ust%3D1559126291689989&psig=AOvVaw3NsIeeVQfpCNDWg-FuLAVU&ust=1559126291689989)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this i had achieved via line render, there is `Draggable` script support provide by MRTK v2. using that and LineRenderer i was able to do it.

Thank you @julia-schwarz for such nice video posting.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to support sharing as well as annotation on holographic objects using MRTK, however a code sample is not yet available for this. Similar to what you would do in old MRTK, you just need deploy a sharing-enabled Unity application to both devices, and have the two devices synchronize their state of the network. An example of this using MRTK v2 is available on this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/P8og3nC5FaQ?t=2259) at 37:37.

The example code to match this behavior is coming soon, I will update this answer once it is posted.

Comment: I tried this way and also for reference seen your reference video.
but still, I am not able to add Sharing in my Unity Application, also one thing I found that spectator view is not available in new MRTK v2.

Comment: We are working on releasing the samples currently and will share when the sample is posted. Stay tuned!

Comment: Thank you @julia-schwarz. 
for be more clear here i am giving you [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=751P0qrCi_E) for reference.

Comment: did you have any update after looking on that video ? it's really back burner for me at the moment.